# Apply template on all PPT charts causes "User-defined type not defined" error

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to apply a template on all charts in my PPT, but get an error stating

> User-defined type not defined

I found the VBA online, and the person sharing it said it worked for him. Any suggestions? I thought it might be the dashes in the pathway, but using "-" or "_" does not help. Also tried removing the last parenthesis after the pathway.

```
Sub ChangeCharts()

    Dim myChart As ChartObject
    For Each myChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    myChart.Chart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
    "Name\Users\Name\Library\Group Containers\UBF8T346G9.Office\User Content\Chart Templates\1.crtx")
    Next myChart

End Sub
```

New VBA tried;

```
Sub ChangeCharts()
  Dim oSl As Slide
  Dim oSh As Shape

  For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
      Select Case oSh.Type
        Case Is = 3  ' Chart created in PPT
        Application.ActivePresentation.ApplyTemplate _
    "name/Users/name/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content/Chart Templates/1.crtx"

      End Select
    Next   ' oSh/Shape
  Next  ' oSl/Slide
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, see the comments below to learn why your sample code can't work in PPT:

```
Sub ChangeCharts()
    ' PPT has no ChartObject type  
    Dim myChart As ChartObject
    ' PPT has no ActiveSheet object
    For Each myChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    myChart.Chart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
    "Name\Users\Name\Library\Group Containers\UBF8T346G9.Office\User Content\Chart Templates\1.crtx")
    Next myChart

End Sub
```

Assuming you're running this from within PPT, you'll need something more like:

```
Sub ChangeCharts
  Dim oSl as Slide
  Dim oSh as Shape

  For Each oSl in ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh in oSl.Shapes
      Select Case oSh.Type
        Case Is = 3  ' Chart created in PPT
          ' apply the template here
          With oSh.Chart
            .ApplyChartTemplate "drive:\path\template_name.crtx"
          End with  ' the chart
        ' Other case statements as needed to
        ' cover embedded/linked OLE objects 
        ' that are Excel charts
      End Select
    Next   ' oSh/Shape
  Next  ' oSl/Slide
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! I really need to learn the basics. I don't think I know what to put for "apply the template here". I've tried the "Application.ActivePresentation.ApplyTemplate _" route, but I get an error saying "Powerpoint could not open file". The template is from Powerpoint, if that makes a difference. Also, where do I post my new code? Still learning SO's functionality.

Comment: Normally you can click the Edit link under your original post and add your updated code (or replace what's there and update your comments to reflect any new issues.  I'll do the same with my answer with some add'l code that should help. Note that you apply chart templates to chart objects, not to the presentation, and they must be chart templates (CRTX files), specifically, not presentation templates (POTX/THMX files)

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveSheet` is an Excel object. I think you want to use `ActiveSlide` for PowerPoint.

Comment: Ok, thanks! That did unfortunately not change anything. The VBA editor wants to highlight "Dim myChart As ChartObject".